# Going from the Direct Product to the Tensor Product

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I am working with vectors of the form $$v = \begin{bmatrix} u_1 \\ \vdots \\ u_n \end{bmatrix},$$ where $u_i \in \Bbb{C}^n$ is a unit vector, which can be thought of as coming $\Bbb{C}^n \oplus ... \oplus \Bbb{C}^n$ (n copies). However, I would like to view this a coming $\Bbb{C}^n \otimes \Bbb{C}^n$, the tensor product, since I am looking at the operator $A \otimes I$ (the kronecker product) acting on them, where $A \in M_n(\Bbb{C})$. So, is there a way of writing $v$ as $x \otimes y$ for $x,y \in \Bbb{C}^n$? I tried with some examples but couldn't discern a pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you won't be able to write $v$ as a tensor product of just two vectors $x,y$; in general it will be of the form
$$
v = x_1 \otimes y_1 + \cdots + x_n \otimes y_n.
$$
In your case, writing $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ for the standard basis of $\mathbb C^n$, you have
$$
v = u_1 \otimes e_1 + \cdots + u_n \otimes e_n.
$$
In fact, the the minimal number of terms necessary in the sum above is the rank of the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\mid & \cdots & \mid\\
u_1 & \cdots &u_n\\
\mid & \cdots & \mid
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: By minimal number of terms, are you saying that some of the $x_i \otimes y_i$ (or $u_i \otimes e_i$) will be zero depending upon the rank of that matrix? You write $v = x_1 \otimes y_1 + \cdots + x_n \otimes y_n$ which means the length is the equal to the number of vectors in $v$; but a priori this doesn't have to be the case, right? Shouldn't the length be some integer other than $n$?

Comment: Yes -- or, more precisely, depending on your choices for the $x_i,y_i$, some of them can be 0. I used $n$ because that is the largest number that always suffices (as the "construction" in my second equation shows), although fewer can suffice. For instance, if each $u_i$ equals a fixed vector $u$, then $v = u \otimes (e_1 + \cdots + e_n)$.